# How do I create a single bar chart from three independent data sources?

Tags: bar-chart, powerbi

### Input

I have three datasets (simplified example below):

- List of students from school A and their age (1200 records)
- List of students from school B and their age (200 records)
- List of students from school C and their age (2000 records)

Every dataset has two columns: `studentId` and `age`.

### Desired result

I want to create a bar chart that shows the distribution of age across these schools. For easy comparison I would like to have:

- one bar chart
- with three legend entries:

  - A
  - B
  - C
- 7 categories:

  - age =< 12
  - age = 13
  - ...
  - age >= 18

### What I have tried

I tried linking the datasets, but due to the different number of students and the various `studentId` formats per school this did not work.

I tried using the `studentId` columns of the three datasets as the value and the `age` column of every dataset as the axis. This only worked one dataset at a time. I needed to "Go to the next level in the hierarchy" to see the other dataset.

How else can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go into Power Query Editor:

[image: Power BI edit queries]

And you will need to add a new column for each datasheet with the legend you want, for example:

[image: Power BI add custom column]

So your tables should look like this:

[image: Power BI query]

[image: Power BI query]

Then merge the tables with **Append Queries as New**:

[image: Power BI Append Queries as New]

Select **Three or more tables**, and add the three tables:

[image: Power BI Three or more tables]

And there you have your three tables merged into one.

[image: Power BI - Power Query Editor]

[image: Power BI Stacked Column Chart]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!